# Equivalent of Swing's pack in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, swing

I am developing a quick app in C#. One thing that I want to do is the equivalent of Swing's (java) `pack()`.  This is a call that allows me to say to a form (Frame in Java), resize yourself to the size of the sum of the components within yourself.

I have searched and searched (the components change dynamically so I cannot simply hardcode the form to the right size) but I cannot find the equivalent method in C#.

Does anyone know what it is called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't even need write code in order to 'pack' the form. In the forms designer, set the form's `AutoSize` property to `true`, and set the `AutoSizeMode` property to `GrowAndShrink`, repeat this for any controls on the form which may also change size.

And voila!

At runtime (only), the form will dynamically resize itself to accommodate all the controls. If you want it to keep a little distance from the controls so that the controls won't 'stick' to the edges, you can set the `Padding` property (I'd recommend at least a value of 12,12,12,12).

Comment: When setting AutoSize on controls such as labels, you will probably want to set the `MaximumWidth` property to force the text to wrap, preventing any long lines from making your form wider than the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Also in xaml:

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, available only if the image is smaller than the screen:

```
Form frm = new Form();
PictureBox pbx = new PictureBox();
pbx.Image = Image.FromFile( _imagePath.Text );
pbx.Dock  = DockStyle.Fill;
frm.Controls.Add( pbx );
frm.Size = pbx.Image.Size;
frm.Show();
```